# how to import multiple custom modules in our own perl script?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have say 100 custom packages like (file1.pm, file2.pm, file3.pm, file4.pm, file5.pm, file6.pm )

Each file contains one function.

i want to import all in my every simple perl script.
 How to import them in easy way.  Please suggest any easiest way?

Comment: Sounds like you really should just refactor to put them into logical modules instead of having huge numbers of single function files.

Comment: Can you give me a simple example of It ?????

Comment: A simple example of refactoring some code I can't see, that does something I know nothing about? No.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this small script to load all 100 modules into it:

```
# pragma
use strict;
use warnings;

# standard modules needed by the script
use Module::Load;

# the loop below loads all 100 of your custom modules (file1.pm, file2.pm, ...)
foreach my $i (1 .. 100)
{
    load "file$i";
}
```

Comment: Not Working Saying "String Found where operator expected near "load "file$i"" { Do you need to predeclare load? }

Comment: Module::Load does a 'require', not a 'use'. The difference might be important in some cases.

Comment: @user970553 Sorry, it's `use` in lowercase, not in uppercase. I edited my answer. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment, I think this is a terrible way to organise your codebase. But assuming that you can't do anything about that, you might want to look at the [Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/module/Toolkit) module.